# How to fit function with fixed parameter?

Tags: parameters, fixed, matlab, curve-fitting

I have an initial parameters for lsqcurvefit like

```
a0 = [value1, value2, value3];
```

and then

```
curvefitoptions = optimset('Display','final','MaxFunEvals',10000,'MaxIter',5000);
[a] = lsqcurvefit(@myfun,a0,x,y,lb,ub,curvefitoptions);
```

I want to be able to fix any of the initial parameters, f.ex. I'm fixing a0(1) and a0(3) at given value and optimizing only a0(2). How to do it? I was trying fixing it in ub and lb, but the same values are not allowed. Of course I can add a bit for ub, but it's not a nice way of doing it :)

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function that fixes the value of the first and third elements. You also need to tweak the start points (2nd argument) and the upper & lower bounds so that they only apply to the 2nd element, e.g.,

```
a = lsqcurvefit( @(x, xdata) myfun([a0(1); x; a0(3)], xdata), a0(2), x, y, ...
        lb(2), ub(2), curvefitoptions );
```

You can easily change this to fix the 2nd and 3rd elements, e.g.,

```
a = lsqcurvefit( @(x, xdata) myfun([x; a0(2); a0(3)], xdata), a0(1), x, y, ...
        lb(1), ub(1), curvefitoptions );
```

Or to fix just the 2nd element

```
a = lsqcurvefit( @(x, xdata) myfun([x(1); a0(2); x(2)], xdata), a0([1,3]), x, y, ...
        lb([1,3]), ub([1,3]), curvefitoptions );
```

To do this in general, start by defining the following (or similar) function

```
function a = interlace( a, x, fix )
a(~fix) = x;
end
```

You can then replace code like `[a0(1); x; a0(3)]` in the examples above with a call to `interlace()`. For example,

```
fix = [1; 0; 1];
a_free = lsqcurvefit( @(x, xdata) myfun( interlace( a0, x, fix ), xdata), ...
    a0(~fix), x, y, lb(~fix), ub(~fix), curvefitoptions );
a = interlace( a0, a_free, fix );
```

My testing of this is limited to the following code:

```
%% A function
myfun = @(x, xdata) x(1) + x(2)*xdata + x(3)./xdata;

%% Some Data
x = [0.036;0.14;0.42;0.49;0.66;0.68;0.76;0.79;0.8;0.85;0.92;0.93;0.96];
y = [0.83;1;0.66;0.53;0.58;0.6;0.64;0.62;0.62;0.55;0.41;0.39;0.33];

%% Initial conditions
a0 = [1; 2; 3];

%% Bounds
lb = [-1; -2; -3];
ub = [0.1; 0.2; 0.3];

%% Fitting options
curvefitoptions = optimset( 'Display', 'iter' );

%% Fit all three parameters
a = lsqcurvefit( myfun, a0, x, y, lb, ub, curvefitoptions )

%% Fix some parameters
fix = [1; 0; 1];

a_free = lsqcurvefit( @(x, xdata) myfun( interlace( a0, x, fix ), xdata), ...
    a0(~fix), x, y, lb(~fix), ub(~fix), curvefitoptions );
a = interlace( a0, a_free, fix );
```

Comment: THANKS! Thats exactly what I needed! Just a quick question: lets say I have var saying if parameter should be fixed (1) or not (0), f.ex. fix = [1 0 1] when 1st and 3rd param is fixed. How to use it to create one  , universal lsqcurefit line, like: a = lsqcurvefit( @(x, xdata) myfun(some_nice_variable, xdata), a0(another_nice_variable), x, y,         lb(1), ub(1), curvefitoptions ); ?

Comment: I added to the answer above with some code that should work in general.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically want is a version of `@myfun` which fixes the values of `a0(1)` and `a0(3)`, which really means it only needs `value2` as a parameter.

Start with your function which takes the input vector with 3 elements

```
function ydata = myfun(x, xdata)
    ...your function which assumes size(x) = [1 3]
end
```

Define another function which fixes the first and third elements

```
function ydata = myfun_fix(value2, xdata)  % value2 should be scalar

    value1_fix = 0; % initialize to your value1
    value3_fix = 0; % initialize to your value3

    x = [value1_fix, value2, value3_fix];

    ydata = myfun(x, xdata);

end
```

Then just pass this new function into `lsqcurvefit`

```
...initialize curvefitoptions
[a] = lsqcurvefit(@myfun_fix, value2, x, y, lb, ub, curvefitoptions);
```

You could possibly make this easier to work with by defining `value1_fix` and `value3_fix` as globals (so you can change them from your main script) instead of as "constants" within `myfun_fix`.

Comment: hmmm.. what If I want to make it more flexible? lets say I want to fix 1 and 3, or 1 and 2, or only 3... ? Thanks...